# Kusto: ingest from a query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Hello all ,

I am currently trying to ingest data using a batch operation . I have my query written as such:

```
.set-or-append tableName with (folder = "rocky")<|
let _Scope = () {
    let N = 4;
    range p from 0 to N-1 step 1
    | partition by p
    {
        functionName((list_of_ids()
        | where hash(something, N) == toscalar(p)), datetime(2020-05-03))
        | extend
            batch_num = toscalar(p)
    }
};
union (_Scope())
```

I want to understand if this would run in parallel for each partition or run sequential ?. If parallel how can i optimize this better ? . Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does this actually queue up N .set-or-append operations? Im having trouble seeing how.

Answer (score 1):

The `partition` operator (which you use in your function) allows you to provide `hint`s to control concurrency:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator

[image]

Regardless, depending on what `functionName()` does (it's not mentioned in the original question), you could consider using the `distributed` option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

> Setting the `distributed` flag to true is useful when the amount of data being produced by the query is large (exceeds 1GB of data) and the query doesn't require serialization (so that multiple nodes can produce output in parallel). When the query results are small it's not recommended to use this flag, as it might generate a lot of small data shards needlessly.

Comment: Appreciate the response. What if i want this to run in a sequential fashion ? Is this already happening that way since the distributed flag is not set ?

Comment: what's the scenario in which you want to run this sequentially? are you trying to implement some kind of "throttling" or limit resources utilization of your command?

Comment: yes. So i am guessing when N=5 here the same function would be running in parallel for different partition, I am talking more about one partition finishes and the next one starts executing .

Comment: if you're insistent on using the `partition` operator - as shown in my reply, you can control the concurrency using `hint`s the operator supports. i would suggest you reconsider your usage of the `partition` operator altogether, and see if you can simply use the `distributed` option of the `.set-or-append` command (as mentioned in my reply)